# Async profiler overhead on Zing

Tags: java, hdrhistogram, async-profiler, azul-zing

Our team is monitoring latency of our application using HdrHistograms. When I attach async profiler to it all percentiles increase dramatically.

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.1 (Ootpa)

JVM: 11.0.8-zing_20.08.2.0-b2-product-linux-X86_64

This is what happens if I attach the profiler with flags -i 1000 -t:
[image]

This is what happens if I attach the profiler with flags -i 100000 -t:
[image]

Decreasing sampling frequency obviously decreases overhead, but it still remains large. I have two questions about it:

1. Are there any other ways to decrease the profiling overhead other than reducing sampling frequency? Maybe there are some magical kernel/JVM flags?
2. Does this overhead materially distort the profile itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The profiling interval is in nanoseconds. You can explicitly specify units, e.g. `-i 10ms`. In your case, `-i 1000` means 1000 nanoseconds, which is not a sane sampling interval: the process will just do continuous sampling instead of the useful work - and, of course, the result profile will not reflect the realistic picture. Start from the default interval (10ms) and decrease it only if absolutely needed.

I have explained the reasonable range in [this answer](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/issues/344#issuecomment-685008790):

> As to the profiling interval, 10 ns is roughly 20-50 cpu instructions.
> It's literally impossible to take samples at such rate. The process
> will do nothing but spending all time inside the profiler.
>
> The default sampling interval in cpu mode is 10ms. This choice is good
> enough for profiling in production: for an average application the
> profiling overhead will be negligible, while the number of samples
> will be enough to collect a meaningful profile.
>
> 1ms interval is usually fine for benchmarks and for profiling real
> applications for a short period of time. Lower intervals are rarely
> useful - maybe, only for capturing a profile of a short running piece
> of code.

Comment: Thank you Andrei. So I guess that we should simply decrease the sampling frequency even further.